# Плагин Aptana в Eclipse

Tags: aptana, eclipse

Здравствуйте!

Есть такая проблема, установил в эклипсе плагин Aptana. Обычно при написании возникает небольшое окошко, которое предлагает дописать что-то. Имеется ввиду всем известное окошко, когда вы только вводите букву, то оно предлагает варианты завершения. Так вот проблема в том, что у меня это окошко прозрачное, оно появляется каждый раз, но ничего в нем прочитать практически нельзя, ибо оно белое. ОС Ubuntu 10.10, Eclipse 3.5.2.

Вопрос в том, как поменять фон у этого окошка? Копался в настройках, но что-то не нашел.

Comment: Была подобная проблема (не с Aptana, а с чем-то еще), и исправилась сама собой после переустановки (по другой причине) Ubuntu, JDK, Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте убить Eclipse и поставить Aptana Studio

Answer (score 0):

Вчера вылечил подобную проблему. Поменял тему в убунте на Dust